# Rounded UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm trying to get a rounded `UIImageView` but it seems to render differently on different devices;

Looks like this on an iPhone Xr:

[image]

Looks like this on an iPhone 7:

[image]

I have a height constraint of 60 and the following code:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    self.userAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = self.userAvatar.frame.height / 2
    self.userAvatar.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.userAvatar.clipsToBounds = true
    self.userAvatar.layer.borderWidth = 0
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you got width constraint or leading and trailing?

Comment: Please set HEIGHT and WIDTH equal constraint.

Comment: I think you set the leading and trailing constraint so instead of leading/trailing set height and width only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you have given the image leading and trailing constraints instead of a fixed width.

To achieve a circle give image view width equal to height.
This happens due to different widths of devices.

Answer (score 3):

If you're managing this view using Interface Builder (i.e. Storyboard or XIB), you can enforce a square shape (which becomes a circle when combined with the rounded corners you already have) for the view directly from there by defining a constraint for its **Aspect Ratio**. No need to code anything.

Control-drag (like you do to create Outlets, Actions, etc.) from the image view to *itself*, and the following popup will appear.

[image: Constraint Popup]

Select **Aspect Ratio**, which will create a constraint matching whatever the view's *current* ratio is (in this example, it's 15:8). If the view was already square, the constraint created should already be correct.

If not, you can find that constraint by clicking the following icon (for the Size inspector):

[image: Size Inspector Icon]

[image: Created Constraint]

From there, you can double-click on that constraint to edit it, and change the **Multiplier** to 1:1:

[image: Constraint Multiplier]

In fact, an even easier option is, once you've Control-dragged from the view to itself, hold down Alt/Opt and the option displayed in the popup will change to **Aspect Ratio (1:1)**, meaning you can set it directly from there without even having to edit the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Constrain the height equal to the width.

And, create a simple `UIImageView` subclass:

```
class RoundedImageView: UIImageView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
    }
}
```

The frame can (and will) change based on view lifecycle. By updating the cornerRadius in `layoutSubviews()` it will keep it "round".